# How to find CSS override

Tags: css

I have a `<div>`. I want it to have a border.

Chrome developer tools shows: `border: 3px !important;` with strikethrough, indicating the border property is superceded. There are no other border entries in the *Inspect* callstack.

How do I find the source of the override?